# Location update in background mode only 10 min

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm developing an iPhone app that will need to keep updating location even when app is in the background.

What I do is:

1. set background mode for Location Update
2. set desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBestForNavigation
3. implement -(void) locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations;
4. call [locationManager startUpdatingLocation]

While the app enter background, it will keep update the location by about only 10 minutes. and then, the update is stop.

Do someone know why?
How can I do a long time location update in background?

Thanks!

Comment: i think the device will get locked(gets into sleep) after 10 mins. You can only run in background when the device is not locked.

Comment: no, 10 min is the limit apps can continue to work in the background before getting suspended.

Comment: So the can still work in background if the device is in sleep mode ?

Comment: I have an app that can save location every 5 minutes all day long in the background, so I don't think theres a timeout issue here.  Probably just not calling the right methods for background location updates.  You might need to look into using these methods for saving location in the background: allowDeferredLocationUpdatesUntilTraveled, performFetchWithCompletionHandler, didFinishDeferredUpdatesWithError

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From Apple Documentation

> You enable location support from the Background modes section of the Capabilities tab in your Xcode project. (You can also enable this support by including the UIBackgroundModes key with the location value in your app’s Info.plist file.) Enabling this mode does not prevent the system from suspending the app, but it does tell the system that it should wake up the app whenever there is new location data to deliver. Thus, this key effectively lets the app run in the background to process location updates whenever they occur.

It seems like setting the background mode should be enough. I got this to work in an app I'm working on, the only difference I see is that I have the `pausesLocationUpdatesAutomatically` set to `NO`.

Comment: Oh! Thanks Simon! I add pausesLocationUpdatesAutomatically = NO to my code and it works fine now!

Answer (score 0):

To solve this in my QT app when the App would go into the background I would stopUpdatingLocation, decrease the accuracy from Best to kCLLocationAccuracyNearestTenMeters AND set a distance filter from None to 50 meters, then startUpdatingLocation.

You could try a lower filter if you need more granular location data.